# Form authentication and session time out

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, session

I am creating a web application which uses form authentication features. I want to implement the concept of session time out and 2 minute warning. I am bit confused regarding how-to implement this concept, which programming method should I used like normal `asp.net`, `jquery` etc. I am not too good in `jquery` or `javascript`. I want to implement session time out concept with alert message which show Ok to continue and End to end session. When user click on Ok all his data wouldn't lose. Also, data will not lose until user doesn't click on either of those two options (OK and End).

I refer number of blog on Google and collected important points like:

- Form Time out should be greater than Session Time
- Use View State = True for all user entry fields
- Use call back instead of post back

But nothing gives me clear understanding of what should I used and how should I implement all this features. My web application had grown in size and I need to add these features globally. How should I do that?

Comment: To do the *two minute warning*, you're going to need to leverage `jQuery` and `AJAX`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few. Your need a little bit of JavaScript or jQuery in order for it to work.

[Alert Session Time out in ASP.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/227382/Alert-Session-Time-out-in-ASP-Net)

Comment: Is it possible to add jquery to global.aspx page so that it'll affect all pages in my application. Can you show me any implementation of that.

Comment: @user2812379 the Global.aspx page doesn't work like that. It is more behind the scenes. Google asp.net MasterPages that should help you out.